# Using Linq is there a way to perform an operation on every element in an Array

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an array

```
var foo = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
```

Using `linq` can I perform an operation on each element instead of doing something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
{
    foo[i] = foo[i] / 2; //divide each element by 2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var foo = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
foo = foo.Select(x=>x/2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Perfect! `foo =` isn't required it looks like @King King

Comment: @ojhawkins It is, because `Select` method does not change source collection. It created new one. So you have to assign it back to `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Those are bad solutions in my opinion. `Select().ToArray()` creates new collection, meaning that it might cause both performance and memory issues for larger arrays. If you want a shorter syntax - write extension methods:

```
static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this T[] array, Func<T,T> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = action(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(this T[] array, Action<T> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            action(array[i]);
        }
    }   
}

//usage
foo.ForEach(x => x/2)
foo.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: *This* should be the correct answer. Creating new arrays should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a single statement.

```
var foo = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Select(m=>m/2);
```

Comment: I think the `Where` `func` returns a `bool` so this doesn't work @Atish Dipongkor

Comment: Edited. Have a look to it. Thanks

Comment: That code is going to produce a couple of errors. You're trying to assign List<int> to int[], and you're using a Where() expression that doesn't return a bool (you probably meant to use Select() instead).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
foo = foo.Select(p => p / 2).toArray();
```